# writing data form text file to excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, file, text

I want to write text file data into excel sheet in my desired columns. I have a text file in which 1260 integer Data is
present in a single column, now I want to copy same data into excel sheet of 10 Columns, each containing 126 integer numbers:
[image: Excel format which i need]

Comment: https://github.com/python-excel can be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually just dump the data as tab separated values (TSV):

```
data [tab] data [tab] data [tab] data [line return]
```

And then you should be able to get Excel to open it with minimal coaxing.